# Как добавить действие в лямбду C++

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Я задумался о создании своего "игрушечного" яп, чисто для того, чтобы убить время. Мне нужно реализовать создание и вызов функций, и единственный способ который я придумал - записать в лямбду.
например есть функция:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    a++;
    return a;
}
```

и я хочу, чтобы она превратилась в это:

```
[]{int a = 5; a++; return a;}
```

т.е. поочерёдно добавлять каждую часть интерпретируемого кода к лямбде, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Код лямбд, как и обычных фуцнкций, нельзя менять во время выполнения. Может вам нужен вектор (или какой-то еще контейнер) с указателям на функции (или с `std::function`)?

Comment: да, это скорее всего подходит. так как преобразить указанную выше функцию в вектор?

Comment: Что-то вроде [вот этого](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1afcb0d09d6b1b47). Но я сомневаюсь, что это вам поможет с созданием языка. Да и работать будет скорее всего не очень быстро.

Comment: Что значит "добавить действие в лямбду"? О чем речь? О модификации функций во время выполнения? О чем-то другом? Потрудитесь осмысленно сформулировать ваш вопрос.

Comment: Существует на свете llvm. Он может помочь с написанием компилятора для языка. Есть даже маленькие уроки по реализации языка. Там вскользь рассказывают как можно парсить код.. https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html . На habr есть перевод.